# PHP built in server unable to load env variables

Tags: php, bash

First I run the following script to set the environment variable:

**bin/env.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

export JWT_SECRET="29dvqfmREKeOgBhGtTogK1pAi+2/x45hKzxONHetwFM="
export DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
export DB_NAME=myapp
export DB_USER=user
export DB_PASS=password
export DB_PORT=3306
```

`bin/env.sh`

Then I run the next script in the same terminal to start development server:

**bin/dev.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

php -d variables_order=EGPCS -S localhost:5001 -t ./public
```

`bin/dev.sh`

The server starts, but when I echo `getenv('DB_USER')` it's blank.

The thing is, if I put `php -d variables_order=EGPCS -S localhost:5001 -t ./public` at the foot of `env.sh` it works.

Why does it work if it's in the same script, but doesn't otherwise? Both scripts are being ran from the same terminal

Comment: Did you try sourcing `env.sh` at the beginning of `dev.sh`? Add a line `source bin/env.sh` in the other  file. Let me know if this worked.

Comment: @Inian that works. Why is that?

Comment: Downvoter explain?

Comment: Happy to help! I didn't downvote! Will upvote now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is none of the variables you defined in `bin/env.sh` is available in the current shell in which you are running the development server. Hence, you need to add a line

`source bin/env.sh`

at beginning of the `bin/dev.sh` to make the variables available in the current session.

There is a built-in `shell` built-in `source` available just for that. On sourcing the file, you are actually executing commands from filename in the current shell environment.

Remember sourcing is different from running a script which "executes" the script in a new shell than the shell originally invoked from.

To explain better with an example:-

Consider `script.sh` with following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "foo: "$(env | grep FOO)
export FOO=foo
echo "foo: "$(env | grep FOO)
```

Before we execute the script first we check the current environment:

```
$ env | grep FOO
```

The variable `FOO` is not defined. On executing the file

```
$ ./script.sh
foo:
foo: FOO=foo
```

Check the environment again:

```
$ env | grep FOO
```

The variable `FOO` is not set.

The script output clearly shows that the variable was set. The check post running the script showed that the variable is not set because the changes were made in a new shell. The current shell spawned a new shell to run the script and all the exported variables are available only till the life time of that spawned shell.
After the script terminates the new shell is destroyed. All changes to the environment in the new shell are destroyed with the new shell. Only the output text is printed in the current shell.

Now we `source` the file:

```
$ source script.sh
foo:
foo: FOO=foo

$ env | grep FOO
FOO=foo
```

You can see now the variable `FOO` is set.

Comment: Amazing answer!

Answer (score 0):

The `export` command makes variables available to sub-shells, it doesn't add them to the parent environment. Use `source` if you want to run a script to update the current environment.